# How to response status 401 on ASP.NET 5 ASP.NET Identity 3.0 RC1

Tags: asp.net-core, http-status-code-401, asp.net-identity-3

In all tutorials that I use the code

```
 app.UseCookieAuthentication(ctx =>
            {
                ctx.AutomaticChallenge = true;
                ctx.Events = new CookieAuthenticationEvents()
                {
                    OnRedirectToLogin = context =>
                    {
                        context.Response.Headers["Location"] = context.RedirectUri;
                        context.Response.StatusCode = 401;
                        return Task.FromResult(0);
                    }
                };
            });
```

Would need to create redirect with status code 401 but because I use ASP.NET identity I'm always automatically redirect to Account/Login page.

Can some wan help me and tell me how to not be redirected to Account/Login and just return status 401.
If I use any other status like 403 that is working perfectly but 401 I can return.
Thanks.

Comment: Why use the identity middleware then?

Comment: Yes that is great question but i would like to use EF Identity implementation for Users and other entities with Authorize attribute but also i would like that if I have WEB API to return 401 not status 200 because is redirected.

Comment: I'm practically trying this approach:
http://wildermuth.com/2015/9/10/ASP_NET_5_Identity_and_REST_APIs

Comment: I guess you can create your own middleware and pick up the redirect and change it to a 401 if you run it after the cookie authentication/identity stuff.

Comment: Thanks on your comments but I think that I will go with IdentityServer3, because I was doing all of this to secure my API calls and maybe IdentityServer3 is the best solution for that now, and the other approaches are not so reliable for me now.
Thanks a lot on your comments you help a lot in my decision.

Comment: Wait for a week (more...), they're going to change all structures again, it will be Identity v.5 and will let you configure your authentication creating only 20 classes and overriding 80 methods... (ah, and don't forget interfaces, it has more than a thousand). And the best, this time it will be well documented.

Answer (score 1):

This fix for this is to add it to the identity provider, rather than as its own authentication step.

So:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, ...) 
{
    ...
    app.UseIdentity();
    ...
    // Ignored, because identity does its own auth and is before it in the middleware
    app.UseCookieAuthentication(...):
```

Instead add your cookie settings to the identity config:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    ...
    // Configure identity service
    services.AddIdentity<AppUser, AppRole>(options =>
    {
        // Set cookie options for that service
        var ctx = options.Cookies.ApplicationCookie;

        // Your code
        ctx.AutomaticChallenge = true;
        ctx.Events = new CookieAuthenticationEvents
        {
            OnRedirectToLogin = context =>
            {
                context.Response.Headers["Location"] = context.RedirectUri;
                context.Response.StatusCode =
                    (int) HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized; 
                return Task.CompletedTask;
            }
        };
    });
```

Comment: I would use:
`context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized;
return Task.CompletedTask;`

Just a bit better